# Webpack ngtemplate-loader and html-webpack-loader ignore relativeTo

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I've got an Angular.js application, built by Webpack, with the following layout:

```
├── app
│   ├── app.js
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── auth
│   │   │   ├── auth.module.js
│   │   │   ├── auth.service.js
│   │   │   └── user.service.js
│   │   ├── footer
│   │   │   └── footer.html
│   │   ├── header
│   │   │   └── header.html
│   │   ├── home
│   │   │   ├── home.html
│   │   │   └── home.module.js
│   │   ├── navigation
│   │   │   └── navigation.html
│   │   ├── right_sidebar
│   │   │   └── right_sidebar.html
│   │   └── util
│   │       ├── util.module.js
│   │       └── util.service.js
│   ├── index.html
│   └── shared
├── assets
│   └── images
│       └── logo.png
├── package.json
└── webpack.config.js
```

In `webpack.config.js` I have configured ngTemplate loader and htmlLoader with `relativeTo` option. Here is the interesting part of `webpack.config.js`:

```
const webpackConfig = {
    ...
    module: {
        ...
        plugins: [
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                inject: "body",
                template: "app/index.html",
                filename: "index.html"
             })
        ],
        loaders: [
            ...
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                exclude: `${path.join(__dirname, "/app/index.html")}`,
                loaders: [`ngtemplate?relativeTo=${path.join(__dirname, "/app")}`, "html"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm trying to `require` a template from `html` file, expecting that `ngTemplate-Loader` respects my `relativeTo` settings, but it won't work.

The load string was: `templateUrl: require("/components/home/home.html")`.

Now, I run this configuration with webpack and it bails out with:

```
ERROR in ./app/components/home/home.module.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' /components/home/home.html in /home/bob/Documents/Projects/bostongene/proto/apps/neoantigens/neoantigens/neoantigens/frontend/app/components/home
 @ ./app/components/home/home.module.js 36:15-52
```

---

Details:

The full code of importing module is here:

`home.module.js`:

```
import angular from "angular"

class HomeController {

    // @ngInject
    constructor($scope, $location, $stateParams, $state) {
        this.$scope = $scope;
        this.$location = $location;
        this.$state = $state;
        this.$stateParams = $stateParams;
    }
}

// @ngInject
function routes($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state("home", {
        url: "/home",
        templateUrl: require("/components/home/home.html"),  
        controller: "HomeController"
    });
}

export default angular.module("home", [])
  .controller('HomeController', HomeController)
  .config(routes);
```

Here's the full error log:

```
Version: webpack 1.12.12
Time: 13977ms
                                     Asset     Size  Chunks       Chunk Names
                        header-f3d4715.jpg   186 kB               
  glyphicons-halflings-regular-f4769f9.eot  20.1 kB               
glyphicons-halflings-regular-448c34a.woff2    18 kB               
 glyphicons-halflings-regular-fa27723.woff  23.4 kB               
  glyphicons-halflings-regular-e18bbf6.ttf  45.4 kB               
  glyphicons-halflings-regular-8988968.svg   109 kB               
                            app.afa8b5d.js  2.48 MB       0       app
                           app.afa8b5d.css   231 kB       0       app
chunk    {0} app.afa8b5d.js, app.afa8b5d.css (app) 2.39 MB [rendered]
    [0] multi app 28 bytes {0} [built]
    [1] ./app/app.js 1.36 kB {0} [built]
    [2] ./bower_components/angular/angular.js 1.09 MB {0} [built]
    [3] ./bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js 142 kB {0} [built]
    [4] ./bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js 25.7 kB {0} [built]
    [5] ./bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js 28.1 kB {0} [built]
    [6] ./bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js 24.5 kB {0} [built]
    [7] ./bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js 169 kB {0} [built]
    [8] ./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css 41 bytes {0} [built]
   [17] ./bower_components/angular-bootstrap/index.js 65 bytes {0} [built]
   [18] ./bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js 240 kB {0} [built]
   [19] ./app/components/home/home.module.js 1.18 kB {0} [built] [1 error]
   [20] ./bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js 259 kB {0} [built]
   [21] ./~/lodash/index.js 411 kB {0} [built]
   [22] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 251 bytes {0} [built]
   [23] ./~/expose-loader?angular!./bower_components/angular/angular.js 329 bytes {0} [built]
   [24] ./assets/styles/style.scss 41 bytes {0} [built]

ERROR in ./app/components/home/home.module.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' /components/home/home.html in /home/bob/Documents/Projects/bostongene/proto/apps/neoantigens/neoantigens/neoantigens/frontend/app/components/home
 @ ./app/components/home/home.module.js 36:15-52
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
         Asset    Size  Chunks       Chunk Names
    index.html  444 kB       0       
    chunk    {0} index.html 412 kB [rendered]
        [0] ./~/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./app/index.html 568 bytes {0} [built]
        [1] ./~/lodash/index.js 411 kB {0} [built]
        [2] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 251 bytes {0} [built]
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
                 Asset    Size  Chunks       Chunk Names
    header-f3d4715.jpg  186 kB               
    chunk    {0} extract-text-webpack-plugin-output-filename 94.2 kB [rendered]
        [0] ./~/css-loader?name=[name]-[hash:7].[ext]!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-loader?includePaths[]=/home/bob/Documents/Projects/bostongene/proto/apps/neoantigens/neoantigens/neoantigens/frontend/app!./assets/styles/style.scss 75.5 kB {0} [built]
        [1] ./~/css-loader/lib/css-base.js 1.51 kB {0} [built]
        [2] ./assets/styles/img/green.png 6.79 kB {0} [built]
        [3] ./assets/styles/img/green@2x.png 10.3 kB {0} [built]
        [4] ./assets/images/landing/header.jpg 64 bytes {0} [built]
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
                                         Asset     Size  Chunks       Chunk Names
      glyphicons-halflings-regular-f4769f9.eot  20.1 kB               
    glyphicons-halflings-regular-448c34a.woff2    18 kB               
     glyphicons-halflings-regular-fa27723.woff  23.4 kB               
      glyphicons-halflings-regular-e18bbf6.ttf  45.4 kB               
      glyphicons-halflings-regular-8988968.svg   109 kB               
    chunk    {0} extract-text-webpack-plugin-output-filename 152 kB [rendered]
        [0] ./~/css-loader?name=[name]-[hash:7].[ext]!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-loader?includePaths[]=/home/bob/Documents/Projects/bostongene/proto/apps/neoantigens/neoantigens/neoantigens/frontend/app!./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css 150 kB {0} [built]
        [1] ./~/css-loader/lib/css-base.js 1.51 kB {0} [built]
        [2] ./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot 86 bytes {0} [built]
        [3] ./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 88 bytes {0} [built]
        [4] ./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff 87 bytes {0} [built]
        [5] ./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf 86 bytes {0} [built]
        [6] ./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg 86 bytes {0} [built]
[16:45:44] Finished 'webpack' after 14 s
[16:45:44] Starting 'build'...
[16:45:44] Finished 'build' after 8.59 μs
```

The full `webpack.config.js`:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const environmentsFile = path.join(__dirname, "/environments.json")
const nodeModulesPath = path.join(__dirname, "/node_modules");
const bowerComponentsPath = path.join(__dirname, "/bower_components")

const webpackConfig = {
    entry: {
        app: ["app.js"]
    },

    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "..", "static"),
        publicPath: "/",
        filename: "app.[hash:7].js"
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.ResolverPlugin(
            new webpack.ResolverPlugin.DirectoryDescriptionFilePlugin("bower.json", ["main"])
        ), // bower; see: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/usage-with-bower
        new ExtractTextPlugin("app.[hash:7].css"),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inject: "body",
            template: "app/index.html",
            filename: "index.html"
        })
    ],

    resolve: {
        root: [path.join(__dirname, "/app"), nodeModulesPath, bowerComponentsPath]
    },

    noParse: [nodeModulesPath, bowerComponentsPath],

    module: {
        preLoaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: [nodeModulesPath, bowerComponentsPath],
                loaders: [`env-replace?prefix=@@&file=${environmentsFile}`]
            }
        ],

        loaders: [
            {
                test: /[\/]angular\.js$/,
                exclude: [nodeModulesPath],
                loader: "exports?angular"
            },

            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: [nodeModulesPath, bowerComponentsPath],
                loaders: ["ng-annotate", "babel?presets[]=es2015&cacheDirectory=true"]
            },

            {
                test: /\.s?css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style", "css?name=[name]-[hash:7].[ext]!postcss-loader!" + `sass?includePaths[]=${path.join(__dirname, "/app")}`)
            },

            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: "json"
            },

            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|otf)$/,
                loader: "file?name=[name]-[hash:7].[ext]"
            },

            {
                test: /\.(png)$/,
                loader: "url?limit=8192&name=[name]-[hash:7].[ext]&mimetype=image/png"
            },

            {
                test: /\.(gif)$/,
                loader: "url?limit=8192&name=[name]-[hash:7].[ext]&mimetype=image/gif"
            },

            {
                test: /\.(jpg)$/,
                loader: "url?limit=8192&name=[name]-[hash:7].[ext]&mimetype=image/jpeg"
            },

            {
                test: /\.woff(2)?$/,
                loader: "url?name=[name]-[hash:7].[ext]&limit=8192&minetype=application/font-woff"
            },

            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                exclude: `${path.join(__dirname, "/app/index.html")}`,
                loaders: [`ngtemplate?relativeTo=${path.join(__dirname, "/app")}`, "html"] //html?attrs[]=div:ng-include
            }
        ]
    },

    postcss: function() {
        return [require('autoprefixer')];
    },

    devServer: {
        contentBase: "./app",
        noInfo: false,
        hot: true,
        inline: true,
        historyApiFallback: true
    }
};

module.exports = webpackConfig;
```

Comment: Did you specified `context` param in webpack config? `context: path.join(__dirname, "app")`

Comment: @BobSponge Hi, Bob Sponge. Sorry to take your time, but I'm really stuck. I've added the full `webpack.conf.js`. No, it doesn't contain that setting.

Comment: You can use path not started with '/' ? e.g. `require("components/home/home.html")`

Comment: @BobSponge It worked. Damn. I guess, that's my bad, though, I've updated all the packages. Thank you.

Comment: @BobSponge Strangely, it included my template into the bundle, but won't display it in Webpack-dev-server. It says: `Failed to load resource http://localhost:8001/components/home/home.html the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`. Why would it ask server at all, if it's got the template in the bundle?

Comment: `ngtemplate-loader` puts template in `$templateCache` and returns name (path to html file) of template to angular's directive. When directive is rendered, angular tries to get template from cache and, if there is not entry, make request to server via http. So, for some reason angular can't get template from cache.

Comment: Your problem is described here: https://github.com/WearyMonkey/ngtemplate-loader#beware-of-requiring-from-the-directive-definition You need to move `require` outside of directive defenition.

Comment: Also you may need to specify `module`:  `ngtemplate?module=home&...`

Comment: @BobSponge Thank you for pointing me to this! I guess, I finally start to understand the functioning of this devilish machine. :)